# Multi-select tree in which parent also is a child

Tags: gui-design, checkboxes, multi-selection, tree, complexity

I am working on a multi-select tree in which the user should be able to select all children of a parent. Normally you would be using the parent checkbox to do so, but in this case it should also be possible to select the parent itself (without any children being active). I've come up with some possible solutions (see Figma link below) and would love to know your opinion on them.

The first flow shows the current situation (so it is not possible to only select the parent). The second shows how it could work without being able to multi-select a group. The rest are possible solutions (although the two latter also do not allow to multi-select groups, e.g. if there were multiple enterprises).

Hope this is clear and am looking forward to your feedback!

Designs: https://www.figma.com/proto/fFuFQ5rJk28TnBG66qhY5L/Back-Office-Work-file-Q4-2021?page-id=1701%3A119452&node-id=1702%3A92650&viewport=350%2C48%2C0.5&scaling=min-zoom&starting-point-node-id=1702%3A92650&show-proto-sidebar=1

Comment: page not found.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a variation of your 5th flow. I'd also indent the children like you did in some of your other solutions.

The problem you are trying to solve is knowing beforehand if the user intends to select parent and children or just the parent. Anything can happen.

What you can do though, is design a default flow and offer a secondary one.

So going back to your 5th solution:

1. The user would click the parent box expecting what ever she is imagining.
2. The Parent should select. At the same time "Select All" should show up allowing the secondary flow.

- Upon clicking the parent checkbox again, I would deselect all. So the user is left with a clean slate, and can go back to step 1 creating a closed loop.